# Sitecore Polls module - Unable to access or delete polls

Tags: c#, sitecore

I've installed the latest version of the Sitecore Polls module (version 3.0.0 rev 090414) onto my Sitecore 6 rev 090120 installation.

I am unable to access or delete poll nodes that I have created post installation, receiving  errors when I attempt to access or delete them in the content editor.

Additionally looking at the binaries in reflector it looks like there is no DeletePoll command defined in the commands namespace.

I've tried contacting Sitecore support about this, but they've just referred me to the shared source modules forum of the SDN.

Has anyone else experienced this and if so, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that these issues are caused through errors in our web.config file. Checking through it looks like references to a previous version of the polls module have been used. Removing them has at least resolved the problem of not being able to delete polls.

Comment: #edit: I've had to get the source code for the module and sift through it to find out what was causing my authorisation error, and the poll user that the module creates and wants to use for poll operations doesn't seem to have access rights, even after making it an administrator. I've changed the PollConstants class to use our administrator credentials instead, and this has resolved the issue.